# Using appium, how to press go button of iOS keyboard?

Tags: appium

I am automating ios application using appium.
In my test case i have to press Go button of Ios keyboard.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `driver.pressKeyCode(80);`. 80 is not for `GO`. Each entity on keyboard have a number. You need to identify the GO number and execute it. It is working for me in android.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.keys` method:

```
device.keys('\n'); //device is Appium browser object
```

or

```
device.keys('\uE007');
```

Source: http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html